# "God reminded them that if they turned away from God, they would be cursed."

Tags: past-tense, conditionals

As for the use of ‘if’, especially when I’m not talking about ‘unreal’ situations, I’m confused about what is the correct way to use it when I talk about something that happened in the past. For example,

> - God reminded them that if they turned away from God, they would be cursed.

(but it may sound like, they will hardly ever turn away from God, right…?)

> - God reminded them that if they have turned away from God, they would be cursed.
> - God reminded them that if they turned away from God, they were to be cursed.
> - God reminded them that if they turn away from God, they will be cursed.

What would be the correct one?

Comment: It's *seriously* "unidiomatic" to repeat the subject name if the referent is also going to serve as a direct or indirect object within the same sentence. So that should be *...they turned away from **Him*** (in this context, the pronoun gets capitalised, but that wouldn't be the case if, say, ***John** reminded them...*).

Comment: @FumbleFingers In some religious sects, it would not be appropriate to give God a sex as if God were a person and not God. It may also not be appropriate to use other pronouns - not sure of the exact details.

Comment: @ColleenV: In some religious sects it's not appropriate to refer to "God" *reminding* anyone about anything, since not all religions feature a godhead that actually communicates with, instructs, or otherwise interacts directly with Mankind. But to a first approximation English is the language of Judeo-Christian (or at least, *Abrahamic*) cultures, and it's a convention of Anglophone orthography that we normally capitalise our written  references to God even if we don't believe He exists. That convention is something people learning English should be aware of, regardless of their beliefs.

Comment: @FumbleFingers My point was that repeating "God" as the object is completely idiomatic in some religious contexts, and  "they turned away from Him" opens a whole different can of worms.

Comment: I don't think I understand. I can't think of any context where it would be idiomatic to repeat the word ***God*** as per OP's example, and I don't see what the speakers religious beliefs have got to do with it really. I reject out of hand the idea that there might be any such entity in the first place, but as an Anglophone I know how to reference this "irrealis" condition. If some religion "outlaws" personal pronoun references to their godhead, that's really their problem with their own language and culture. They can't impose any such strictures on the English language.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Why can't religious texts have certain constructions that are common in that context in the same way that legalese and headlines have well-recognized differences from standard English? Context matters with English, especially when you're talking about what is idiomatic. I'm not arguing about the validity of any particular belief; I'm talking about the conventions used in a certain group of texts.

Comment: I don't think I'm arguing about the validity of any particular belief over and above the fact that I don't buy into *any* theistic position. But even if there *is* some natively Anglophone religious community with "odd" conventions about using personal pronouns in relation to their god (as Muslims don't like *depictions* of theirs), I don't see why people learning English need to be told about that *here*. Their church elders can tell them what they need to do, but I'd have thought that here on ELL we're only really concerned with *mainstream* Anglophone conventions.

Answer (score 0):

You're not really asking about *if*, but about how to use tenses.

God said "If you turn away from me you will be cursed".

"God *reminded* them that if they turned away they would be cursed." There is no problem with this, it's the simplest way of restating what was said in the past.

"...if they have turned away" suggests that there's a strong possibility that they already have.

"They were to be cursed" suggests that the cursing was definitely going to happen.

Comment: Does the phrase "they were to be cursed" signify it's certain to happen only if the condition satisfies? I mean, does it mean 'they will certainly be cursed 'if' they turn away from God'? or does it mean 'they are certainly gonna turn away from God and be cursed'?

Comment: one more question! If I want to change the sentence 'God reminded them that if they turned away from God, they would be cursed.' into a conditional one which is low in possibility, what would it be like?  1. God reminded them 'if they turned away from God they would be cursed' ...? are there any other options?

Comment: 'They were to be cursed' _on its own_ means that it was certain to happen. Used with the 'if' phrase, I suppose it implies a stronger possibility. You could express a lower possibility by saying 'If [ever] they were to turn away from God...'

Comment: God reminded them that if they turned away from God, https://www.stonegableblog.com/everyone-right-eyes/ OR from their Lord